# Contrapositive of a statement.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would I find the contrapositive of the following implication:

If $ x^2 + x - 2 < 0 $, then $x>-2$ and $x<1$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contrapositive in this case is:

If not ($x>-2$ and $x<1$) then not ($x^2+x-2<0$)

Or equivalently:

If $x\le-2$ **or** $x\ge1$ then $x^2+x-2\ge0$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to just telling you what the contrapositive is in your case (like you aksed..):

Given you asked this question, at least one of the following three is not known to you:
1. The contrapositive of $a \rightarrow b$ is the logically equivalent $\lnot b \rightarrow \lnot a$.
2. De Morgan's Law: $\lnot (c \land d)$ is logically equivalent to $\lnot c \lor \lnot d$
3. Trichotomy Property: For every two real numbers $a,b$, exactly one of $(=,<,>)$ relates them.